Как типизировать объект, у которого 1 ключ вариативен?
с бэка приходит массив объектов с такой структурой
export interface IUserNotifySubscribesResponse {
    id: number
    mId: number
    uId: number
    notifyType: UserNotifyType
    notifyRulesJson: string
  }


  export enum UserNotifyType {
    UNOTIFY_BY_MODEL,
    UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE,
    UNOTIFY_BY_PLATFORM,
  }


для работе на фронте , создается новый тип в котором notifyRulesJson парсится
  export interface IUserNotifySubscribes extends IUserNotifySubscribesResponse {
    notifyRulesObj: RulesObj
  }

RulesObj в свою очередь вариативен
 export type RulesObj = SubscriptionSettings | CasesSettings | PlatformSettings

  export interface SubscriptionSettings {
    modelNotify: boolean
    defect: boolean
  }

  export interface PlatformSettings {
    platform: boolean
    sms: boolean
    email: boolean
  }
  
  export interface CasesSettings {
    cases: boolean
  }



как сделать, чтобы TypeScript понимал, что именно приходит в RulesObj
Полагаю тут нужны дженерики,
export interface IUserNotifySubscribes<T extends RulesObj> extends IUserNotifySubscribesResponse {
  notifyRulesObj: T
}

но в таком случае не совсем понимаю как нужно типизировать массив, ведь в нем объекты всех 3х вариаций

В вашем случае не нужны дженерики, воспользуйтесь защитой типа (Type Guards)
Создайте интерфейс с перечислением всех реализаций:
export interface SubscriptionSettings {
  modelNotify: boolean
  defect: boolean
}

export interface PlatformSettings {
  platform: boolean
  sms: boolean
  email: boolean
}

export interface CasesSettings {
  cases: boolean
}

export type RulesObj = SubscriptionSettings | CasesSettings | PlatformSettings

export interface UserNotifySubscribes extends UserNotifySubscribesResponse {
  notifyRulesObj: RulesObj
}

Затем создайте функции которые будут проверять ключи или любые другие данные с указанным типом.
export function isUserNotifySubscriptionSettings(value: RulesObj): value is SubscriptionSettings {
  return 'modelNotify' in value;
}
export function isUserNotifyPlatformSettings(value: RulesObj): value is PlatformSettings {
  return 'platform' in value;
}
export function isUserNotifyCasesSettings(value: RulesObj): value is SubscriptionSettings {
  return 'cases' in value;
}

главная функция, которая обрабатывает логику, должна быть фабрикой и проверять необходимые данные для корректного определения типа:
export async function main() {
  const result: UserNotifySubscribes = await getUserNotifySubscribes();

  if (isUserNotifySubscriptionSettings(result.notifyRulesObj)) {
    console.log(result.notifyRulesObj.modelNotify);
  } else if (isUserNotifyPlatformSettings(result.notifyRulesObj)) {
    console.log(result.notifyRulesObj.platform);
  } else if (isUserNotifyCasesSettings(result.notifyRulesObj)) {
    console.log(result.notifyRulesObj.cases);
  }

  // Another logic
}

Не могу подсказать более элегантного и type safety решения. Уверен есть и другие решения которые не нарушают какие-то принципы.
Весь код тут:


export interface UserNotifySubscribesResponse {
  id: number
  mId: number
  uId: number
  notifyType: NotifyType
  notifyRulesJson: string
}

export enum NotifyType {
  UNOTIFY_BY_MODEL,
  UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE,
  UNOTIFY_BY_PLATFORM,
}

export interface SubscriptionSettings {
  modelNotify: boolean
  defect: boolean
}

export interface PlatformSettings {
  platform: boolean
  sms: boolean
  email: boolean
}

export interface CasesSettings {
  cases: boolean
}

export type RulesObj = SubscriptionSettings | CasesSettings | PlatformSettings

export interface UserNotifySubscribes extends UserNotifySubscribesResponse {
  notifyRulesObj: RulesObj
}

export async function getUserNotifySubscribes(): Promise < UserNotifySubscribes > {
  const response: UserNotifySubscribesResponse = {
    id: 0,
    mId: 0,
    uId: 0,
    notifyType: NotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE,
    notifyRulesJson: '',
  }

  const result = {}
  as UserNotifySubscribes;
  Object.assign(result, response, {
    notifyRulesObj: {
      cases: false,
    }
  });
  return result;
}

export function isUserNotifySubscriptionSettings(value: RulesObj): value is SubscriptionSettings {
  return 'modelNotify' in value;
}
export function isUserNotifyPlatformSettings(value: RulesObj): value is PlatformSettings {
  return 'platform' in value;
}
export function isUserNotifyCasesSettings(value: RulesObj): value is SubscriptionSettings {
  return 'cases' in value;
}

export async function main() {
  const result: UserNotifySubscribes = await getUserNotifySubscribes();

  if (isUserNotifySubscriptionSettings(result.notifyRulesObj)) {
    console.log(result.notifyRulesObj.modelNotify);
  } else if (isUserNotifyPlatformSettings(result.notifyRulesObj)) {
    console.log(result.notifyRulesObj.platform);
  } else if (isUserNotifyCasesSettings(result.notifyRulesObj)) {
    console.log(result.notifyRulesObj.cases);
  }

  // Another logic
}




Так можно, но неудобно каждый раз через функцию проверять вместо сравнения поля. Да и в рантайме лишняя работа на вызов функции.

@Qwertiy мы говорим о TS, а не о JS, использовать type guards рекомендовано документацией, данный подход изолирует проверку и беспокоится за то, что при изменении интерфейса упадёт фабрика тоже не нужно будет.

Вероятность, что способ проверки типа изменится с поля notifyType на что-то ещё - где-то около 0. А вот в твоём варианте с гардами на RulesObj вместо IUserNotifySubscribes, вполне может случиться, что добавится совпадающее поле и гард придётся переписывать. К тому же, теряется красивая возможность использовать switch по типу. Про js никто не говорил. У меня ж вполне на ts ответ.

type IUserNotifySubscribes = {
  [key in UserNotifyType]: IUserNotifySubscribesResponse & {
    notifyType: key,
    notifyRulesObj: {
      [UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_MODEL]: SubscriptionSettings,
      [UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE]: CasesSettings,
      [UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_PLATFORM]: PlatformSettings,
    }[key]
  }
}[UserNotifyType]

Код полностью: playground
export interface IUserNotifySubscribesResponse {
  id: number
  mId: number
  uId: number
  notifyType: UserNotifyType
  notifyRulesJson: string
}

export enum UserNotifyType {
  UNOTIFY_BY_MODEL,
  UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE,
  UNOTIFY_BY_PLATFORM,
}

export type RulesObj = SubscriptionSettings | CasesSettings | PlatformSettings

export interface SubscriptionSettings {
  modelNotify: boolean
  defect: boolean
}

export interface PlatformSettings {
  platform: boolean
  sms: boolean
  email: boolean
}

export interface CasesSettings {
  cases: boolean
}

type IUserNotifySubscribes = {
  [key in UserNotifyType]: IUserNotifySubscribesResponse & {
    notifyType: key,
    notifyRulesObj: {
      [UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_MODEL]: SubscriptionSettings,
      [UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE]: CasesSettings,
      [UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_PLATFORM]: PlatformSettings,
    }[key]
  }
}[UserNotifyType]

declare const data: IUserNotifySubscribes[]

for (const x of data) {
  switch (x.notifyType) {
    case UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_PLATFORM:
      console.log(x.notifyRulesObj.platform)
      break

    case UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_MODEL:
      console.log(x.notifyRulesObj.defect)
      break
    
    case UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE:
      console.log(x.notifyRulesObj.cases)
      break
  }
}


Впервые вижу такой вариант решения, для меня c точки зрения понимания выглядит сложновато, но на заметку взял, спасибо!

@MoloF, тут ещё интересный вариант предложили - похож на мой, но всё же другой)

Можно также использовать Union Types
type IUserNotifySubscribes = IUserNotifySubscribesResponse & ({
  notifyType: UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_MODEL;
  notifyRulesObj: SubscriptionSettings;
} | {
  notifyType: UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE;
  notifyRulesObj: CasesSettings;
} | {
  notifyType: UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_PLATFORM;
  notifyRulesObj: PlatformSettings;
});

Полное решение:
TS Playground
export interface IUserNotifySubscribesResponse {
  id: number
  mId: number
  uId: number
  notifyType: UserNotifyType
  notifyRulesJson: string
}

export enum UserNotifyType {
  UNOTIFY_BY_MODEL,
  UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE,
  UNOTIFY_BY_PLATFORM,
}

export interface SubscriptionSettings {
  modelNotify: boolean
  defect: boolean
}

export interface PlatformSettings {
  platform: boolean
  sms: boolean
  email: boolean
}

export interface CasesSettings {
  cases: boolean
}

type IUserNotifySubscribes = IUserNotifySubscribesResponse & ({
  notifyType: UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_MODEL;
  notifyRulesObj: SubscriptionSettings;
} | {
  notifyType: UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE;
  notifyRulesObj: CasesSettings;
} | {
  notifyType: UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_PLATFORM;
  notifyRulesObj: PlatformSettings;
});

const userNotifySubscribes: IUserNotifySubscribes[] = []; // Получение данных с сервера

// Можно сужать тип через switch case
userNotifySubscribes.forEach((item) => {
  switch (item.notifyType) {
    case UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_MODEL:
      item.notifyRulesObj; // SubscriptionSettings
      break;
    case UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE:
      item.notifyRulesObj; // CasesSettings
      break;    
    case UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_PLATFORM:
      item.notifyRulesObj; // PlatformSettings
      break;
  }
});

// Можно сужать тип через if
userNotifySubscribes.forEach((item) => {
  if (item.notifyType === UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_MODEL) {
    item.notifyRulesObj; // SubscriptionSettings
  } else if (item.notifyType === UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_WEBCASE) {
    item.notifyRulesObj; // CasesSettings
  } else if (item.notifyType === UserNotifyType.UNOTIFY_BY_PLATFORM) {
    item.notifyRulesObj; // PlatformSettings
  }
});


Красиво. Не задумывался, что так можно) Похоже на моё, но реализовано вроде как проще) С другой стороны, мой накладывает требование на все значения енума: если в UserNotifyType добавят ещё значение, то в моём коде ts потребует дописать тип, а в твоём - нет.

Только ты скобки пропустил. Я поправил, если с чем-то не согласен, скажи.

@Qwertiy верно поправил, спасибо! Этот прием я часто видел на просторах интернета и сам применяю. А вот твой для меня был открытием. Да, при добавлении значения в enum твой способ понадежнее будет
